# Use of the も particle

Tags: song-lyrics, particle-も

I'm dissecting some Japanese lyrics to improve my Japanese, but I had a hard time finding out how も is used in here,

> 何ページ**も**ついやして     　
>   綴られた僕らの気分

I've looked it up in serveral websites and found one that said も is used with 何 to say "many of something" (Ex: 何ページも = many/several pages).

Could anyone confirm this or add more practical or common uses of the も particle?

Answer (score 1):

When 何 is used with も, it is known as an **indeterminate quantifier** and indicates the speaker's feeling that an amount is large (without specifying an exact number). 何ページも is a perfect example of that and could be translated as "many pages", as you mentioned.

Other examples:

何回も many times
何人も many people
何万人も many tens of thousands of people
etc ...